How to Define a Recursive Function with Constraints in Z3 Java API?
I am working with the Z3 Java API and trying to define a function f(x) = x + 1 via using recursive API. However, instead of directly defining the function as y = x + 1, I want to use constraints to represent this relationship. Below is the code I have written:
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        FuncDecl f = ctx.mkRecFuncDecl(ctx.mkSymbol("f"),
                new Sort[]{ctx.mkIntSort()},
                ctx.mkIntSort());
        Expr x = ctx.mkFreshConst("x", ctx.mkIntSort());
        Expr y = ctx.mkFreshConst("y", ctx.mkIntSort());
        Expr cons = ctx.mkEq(ctx.mkAdd(x, ctx.mkInt(1)), y);
        ctx.AddRecDef(f, new Expr[]{x}, y);
        Solver solver = ctx.mkSolver();
        solver.add(cons);

        solver.add(ctx.mkNot(ctx.mkEq(ctx.mkInt(2), ctx.mkApp(f, ctx.mkInt(1)))));

        assert solver.check() == Status.UNSATISFIABLE; //Fail
    }

the function does not behave as expected. The constraint f(1) != 2 should be unsatisfiable, but it seems like the constraints are not correctly applied.
How can I correctly define function f(x) = x + 1 using constraints in the Z3 Java API?

In general, when you're defining a function, simply return the defining expression. (i.e., do not return a "free" variable with constraints on it; simply build the expression itself.)
So, you should write:
import com.microsoft.z3.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        FuncDecl f = ctx.mkRecFuncDecl(ctx.mkSymbol("f"),
                new Sort[]{ctx.mkIntSort()},
                ctx.mkIntSort());
        Expr x = ctx.mkFreshConst("x", ctx.mkIntSort());
        ctx.AddRecDef(f, new Expr[]{x}, ctx.mkAdd(x, ctx.mkInt(1)));
        Solver solver = ctx.mkSolver();
        solver.add(ctx.mkNot(ctx.mkEq(ctx.mkInt(2), ctx.mkApp(f, ctx.mkInt(1)))));

        System.out.println(solver.check());
    }
}

When I run this, I get:
Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
UNSATISFIABLE

So, you do get UNSATISFIABLE as you'd expect. I didn't inspect the source of unchecked-unsafe operations here, which is probably a good idea to look at for additional safety.

In some cases, I cannot construct the output directly from the input through an arithmetic expression. For example, the input is x1 and x2, and the output y is either x1 or x2, and I cannot determine under what conditions it is x1 or x2. How should I deal with this situation?

Then, by definition you can’t use mkRecFuncDecl, since it only allows functions to be defined. You need to use uninterpreted functions with quantified asserts instead. (Decidability will depend on how complicated those quantified assertions are.)
